# How does Linux translate a physical address to (possibly multiple) virtual address?

Tags: linux, virtual-memory, memory-management

From my understanding, when Linux swaps a physical page frame in/out RAM, it needs to set valid bit for all virtual pages mapping into this physical page. Mapping a virtual page to physical page frame seems to be well explained in textbooks, but how does the kernel find all virtual pages from a physical page frame? Actual implementation in Linux source code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each physical page of memory is tracked in the kernel using [struct page](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.2/source/include/linux/mm_types.h#L30). This allows the kernel to describe how each page is used; in particular, for anonymous and file-backed mappings, the [mapping](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.2/source/include/linux/mm_types.h#L86) field points to the [`address_space`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.2/source/include/linux/fs.h#L445) structure used to describe the mapped object.

For code which needs to find virtual mappings using a given physical page, the kernel provides a set of [reverse mapping functions](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.2/source/mm/rmap.c). These allow the reverse mappings for anonymous mappings and file-backed mappings to be walked. For example, [`try_to_unmap`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.2/source/mm/rmap.c#L1699) walks the maps looking for any use of a given physical page, so that it can unmap it. `shrink_page_list` [calls `try_to_unmap`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.2/source/mm/vmscan.c#L1352) when it decides it needs to unmap a page which is mapped into processes.